# Is there a way to know which rule filtered an email?

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules, spam

My Mail.app has at least 100 rules with thousands of conditions and sometimes I get mail filtered that was not supposed to be filtered.

All my filters work by moving unwanted stuff to the trash.

Is there a way to discover what rule in particular put the email there?

thanks

Comment: Wow, that's a whole bunch of rules; can the behavior be duplicated easily — does it happen often?

Comment: Yes, I hate spam. Yes, I have an email that I put on the inbox. I quit mail.app. When I run mail.app again the mail is back to the trash.